# Error: [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client, fetch error

Tags: javascript, express, http-headers, fetch, http-error

This code doesn't allow me to make a fetch request when I invoque sendPushMessages(message) due to HTTP ERRORS but I have no idea why.

The console shows:
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Moreover, if I comment:      res.status(200).send({shop: shop[0]}); the code isn't still working.

```
const {models} = require('../models');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

exports.findshop = async (req, res, next) => {

  sendPushMessages = async (message) => {
    try{
      let response = await fetch('https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(message),
      });

      let responsed = await response.json();
      console.log(responsed);
    }
    catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  }

  try {
      console.log(req.body.latitud)
      console.log(req.body.longitud)
      const user = req.user;
      const shops = await models.Shop.findAll({
        include:[{ model: models.Product, as: 'placements'}]
      });

      const shop = shops.filter(shp => {
        if (Math.abs(shp.latitud - req.body.latitud) <= 0.001 && Math.abs(shp.longitud - req.body.longitud) <= 0.001){
          return shp;
        }
      });

      if (shop[0] && user) {
        shop[0].placements.forEach(item => {
          if (item.dataValues.isoffer){
            const message = {
                to: user.pushtoken,
                sound: 'default',
                title: '¡Ofertón! ¡No te lo puedes perder!',
                body: item.productname + ' ' + item.price.toString() + '€',
            };
            sendPushMessages(message);
          }
        })  
        res.status(200).send({shop: shop[0]});
      } else {
        res.status(200).send({shop: null});
      }
  } catch (error) {
      next(error);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code you show (it would be useful to see the top level request handler too so we can see the whole flow of the code), there is an issue if `sendPushMessages()` has an error.  It will call `next(err)` and keep going in your outer loop which will try to send at least one more response, causing the error message you get for `ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT`.

You need some error handling upon calling `sendPushMessages()` so you can stop your loop when it has an error.  So, that needs to be fixed.  One simple way to fix that would be to remove the `catch()` block from `sendPushMessages()` and just let that rejection propagate back to the caller.  Then, add an `await` in front of your call to `sendPushMessages(message)` like this:

```
await sendPushMessages(message);
```

So, when `sendPushMessages()` rejects, you will hit your own `catch` block in `findshop()` and will call `next(error)` just once and not send any other response.

If the rest of your question is why are you getting an error when you try to access `https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send'`, then we can only probably help if you can share what the error is your actually getting.  You should be able to add `console.log(error)` to your `catch()` handler so you can log the actual error you are getting.  In my server code, I always log the actual lowest level error that is occurring because that is often needed to debug why a problem is happening.

Comment: If I do what you just said, it appears the following error: await sendPushMessages(message);
            ^^^^^
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1071:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1121:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1177:10)

Also, I can't start the server.

Comment: @AitorEncinas - Change your `.forEach()` to a regular `for` loop.  You will pretty much want to abandon `.forEach()` for asynchronous code.

Answer (score 0):

This the error that appears:

fetch is not defined
POST /location 500 8.371 ms - 32
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:526:11)
at ServerResponse.header (/home/aitorencinas/Documents/Universidad/TFG/servidor/server_express/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
at ServerResponse.send (/home/aitorencinas/Documents/Universidad/TFG/servidor/server_express/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
at done (/home/aitorencinas/Documents/Universidad/TFG/servidor/server_express/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1004:10)
at Object.exports.renderFile (/home/aitorencinas/Documents/Universidad/TFG/servidor/server_express/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:374:12)
at View.exports.__express [as engine] (/home/aitorencinas/Documents/Universidad/TFG/servidor/server_express/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:417:11)
at View.render (/home/aitorencinas/Documents/Universidad/TFG/servidor/server_express/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
at tryRender (/home/aitorencinas/Documents/Universidad/TFG/servidor/server_express/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
at Function.render (/home/aitorencinas/Documents/Universidad/TFG/servidor/server_express/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
at ServerResponse.render (/home/aitorencinas/Documents/Universidad/TFG/servidor/server_express/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:7)

Comment: So, `fetch()` by itself is a browser thing and is not available in nodejs unless you are adding some third party library that simulates that interface such as node-fetch.  Also, this should not be in an answer (since it is not an answer).  You should use the "edit" link below your question to ADD more info to your question.